# How to schedule appointment in Outlook using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, outlook

For sending the mail, we can do like `<a href="mailto:user@domain.com"></a>`. Is there any similar functionality in Javascript to schedule an Outlook appointment/meeting? If not, how to achieve this in all the browsers?

Comment: not in vanilla Javascript there isn't.

Comment: not possible in javascript..But you using ActiveX object